# Hide bottom bar or download button in iPushPull

Tags: wordpress, excel, push, pull

I am embedding iPushPull in a WordPress Site. I have setup all and data is showing properly on this page:

https://www.daytradingcrudeoil.com//test-data/

I want to hide the whole bottom bar or just share and download button. For that I tried this:

```
[ipushpull_page folder="r1" page="MyDataPage" height="325px" btn_share="no" btn_download="no"]
```

as in the example on iPushPull page but nothing happens, buttons are still there.

How can I remove or hide these buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customising or hiding the bottom bar is only possible if you have a paid-for package. The bottom bar cannot be changed if you have a free account. See the answer on the [FAQs page for the iPushPull WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ipushpull/faq/).